# Error importing scipy.special.expit

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I want to import the sigmoid function available at `scipy.special.expit`.

If I use `import scipy.special.expit as sigmoid` (or without the "as sigmoid") I get a "No module called expit" error.

If I use `from scipy import special`, then using `special.expit(N)` **works**.

If I use `from scipy import special.expit as sigmoid`, invalid syntax at `special.expit` (the dot).

If I use `from scipy.special import expit`, `special` is not defined error.

So... how the hell can I import the `expit`function assigning the "sigmoid" alias?

Comment: `from scipy.special import expit` should work.  Please show the complete error message.

Comment: ok I found the problem. Yes, it works, the problem was that still I had the call to `special.expit(N)`, so obviously the interpreter didn't find a defined `special`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I noted in a comment,

```
from scipy.special import expit
```

should work.  To import `expit` with the name `sigmoid`, use

```
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid
```

Comment: Right, for SciPy >= 0.10.