# Module 'scipy.special' has no 'expit' member in Python / SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I try to use expit(x) from SciPy. But I get this error message:

> Module 'scipy.special' has no 'expit' member

This is my code:

```
import numpy
import scipy.special
```

[...]

```
def Activation(self, ActivationInput):
    self.ActivationOutput = scipy.special.expit(ActivationInput)
    return self.ActivationOutput
```

`scipy` is red underlined in VScode when I try to us it in the function `Activation`

The solution via [Error importing scipy.special.expit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225496/error-importing-scipy-special-expit) was not satisfying and doesn't work.

I use Python 3.7, NumPy 1.14.5 and SciPy 1.1.0.

Other functions work, but all Ufuncs from `scipy.special` get this error message.

Comment: Adding a `print(dir(scipy.special))` will tell you what actually is being imported from that module, which might give a hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: That sounds like an IDE configuration issue.

Comment: @jasonharper I have done this. I shows a list of all functions. expit is one of the listed functions.

Comment: @user2357112 Any suggestion what I have configured wrong?

Answer (score 3):

All of the ufuncs in `scipy.special` are written in C and so pylint cannot find the proper definition.  You can tell pylint to ignore the module by adding the option `--ignored-modules=scipy.special` to pylint.

## For VSCode:

Adding `--ignored-modules=scipy.special` via the options GUI or directly to the settings.JSON file is possible, but it turns off the default options that VSCode uses with pylint.

To solve this issue, you can add both the original default options as well as the `--ignored-modules` flag to the settings.json file.

- Type `[CTRL]+[Shift]+p` to open the command search
- Search for `open settings (JSON)`, which will open you settings file.
- in `settings.JSON` add the key / value pairs so you file has the following

```
{
    // any other options for VSCode

    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=all",
        "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned",
        "--enable=unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode",
        "--ignored-modules=scipy.special"
        ],
}
```

The first 3 lines are the default options used by VSCode for pylint.  The 4th line tells pylint to ignore the `scipy.special` module, which will turn off the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be a Pylint issue like [this one](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2140). Did you try if you can execute your code?

As a **workaround** you could try and disable the no-member/E1101 rule:

```
#pylint: disable=no-member
self.ActivationOutput = scipy.special.expit(ActivationInput)
```